# Linking JOOMLA! database to a flutter application

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, database

I created a Joomla website which has some forms to be filled. Is it possible to link this form to a database that a flutter mobile application I developed can retrieve data from?

For example, the website has a form to fill with a person's details and on the mobile app, I have a page to display this information in the desired way. I just need to know how to link My Joomla website to the application.

Comment: While you probably feel that this question is a singular and focused one, the truth is that it presents as an unattractive question to most volunteers because it requires a disproportionate amount of effort from volunteers versus the amount of effort you have proven in your question.  As is, your "question" is requesting a complete tutorial because you have shown no attempt to self-solve.  This is known as a "requirements dump" and these are unsavoury because they treat volunteers as free code-writers.  This is not the goal of any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Please show us all of the relevant research that you have conducted and if you have coded anything, it is your responsibility to express exactly where you are stuck and include any error messages or clues.  Please enhance your question by editing it.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to link my Joomla website to  mobile app . No one has to tell me how to do it, just guide me to an extension or certain technology I should look into.

Comment: I found an extension called ZOOModsPlus. Is this the only approach available for Joomla websites?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, you want to access the data in your joomla database from an external application? Does your third party mobile application allow you to write custom code? If so it should be relatively straightforward, connect to Joomla and retrieve whatever you need. I'm not familiar with that mobile applcation so can't comment on the functionality

Comment: @jonboy flutter is made by Google you can creative native mobile applications with it.  Yes you can write custom code.  Connecting to Joomla! is less straight forward as you need a database connection, which possibly you don't want to provide a native 3rd party application.  I think an API is a little safer.

Answer (score 3):

To connect Joomla! to a 3rd party app you will need an API connection.

There are a few options:

You can install Jbackend on Joomla and use rest API to access the database. https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jbackend/

You can install TechJoomla's API https://techjoomla.com/free-downloads/rest-api-for-joomla

You can wait for Joomla! 4 which is currently in Beta and has a built in API. https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Api_Specification

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Joomla is that there are just in-built fields connected to the following content types: Articles, Categories, Users, User Groups. There are also ones connected to banners and some other components, but are much less exposed than the aforementioned main content types.

Joomla 4 (as James commented) does bring to the table the following: Custom fields and REST API. So even though I haven't tried REST API, I can tell you that custom fields are a little bit underwhelming (can be only connected to the 5 default content types, including the Contacts type) and templating is a little rough around edges. Field value is stored in table _fields_values with key-pair field_id item_id. Field types and useful classes can be found in this [diagram](https://api.joomla.org/cms-4/classes.svg).

There is also the option of fully fledged CCK such as [SEBLOD](https://www.seblod.com/), which is unfortunately still in [beta (on GitHub)](https://github.com/Octopoos/SEBLOD/tree/4.0-dev) for Joomla 4. Having a CCK you can create any field you like, and have it stored in database as seblod(standard)/JSON storage format and article/user/custom content object [(details about storage)](https://www.seblod.com/resources/manuals/advanced/understanding-the-storage). SEBLOD also gives the option to create custom content types, outside of the default A/C/U/UG types. Since Joomla exposes content managed by SEBLOD (component) through plugins, what remains to see is how well will it serve the custom content via REST API.

As a bonus side, SEBLOD is quite capable for site CRUD operations. They even claim: "SEBLOD is an Application Builder and a Content Construction Kit.
It helps to create/manage custom online applications & full-featured websites."

I can only say that still 7/8 years later I return to it with pleasure knowing it will do even more than what's on the tin, and there is still a vibrant [community forum](https://www.seblod.com/community/forums) if need arise to look for a solution.

All praise aside, I was not able to configure (beta) SEBLOD under Joomla 4.

As you can notice I haven't mentioned Flutter since in that regard I consider myself a beginner, dipping my toes for the moment only in consuming other framework APIs (AliceApp) and Rive animations.

As far as the original question go, James already gave most valuable insights. Since form is already working with user data, custom fields can be attached to user data type.